# For loop not running in c language cs50 ide

Tags: c, for-loop, command-line-arguments, computer-science, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

string crypt(string msg, int key);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Sorry\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        string h = get_string("ipt: ");
        h = crypt(h, atoi(argv[2]));
    }
}

string crypt(string msg, int key)
{
    string c = "";
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    int len = strlen(msg);
    for(int i = 0; i > len; i++)
    {
        char t = (msg[i] + key) % 26;
        printf("%c", t);
    }
    return c;
}
```

In this code it says [**Segmentation Fault**](https://www.bing.com/search?q=Segmentation%20fault%20(core%20dumped)&cvid=8f9ce1641e1b4a58be1f60464c34bc97&aqs=edge.2.69i57j0j69i59l2j0l3.10662j0j1&pglt=385&FORM=ANNTA1&PC=W037)

I Don't Understand the Problem

I'm Trying a lot But Don't get it I'm not trying to access Memory **"That Doesn't belong to me"** as the wiki says:-

> Core Dump/Segmentation fault is a specific kind of error caused by accessing memory that “does not belong to you.”

I'm Using the [cs50 ide](https://ide.cs50.io) on `MS Edge`.

This code is supposed To Output the Coded version of the `input:` Text.

Plz help I Don't Understand The problem.

The Error Appears After The text Is entered.

Comment: One of the many reasons CS50 is a horrible course: the "string" define makes students believe that C has a string type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters if `argc` is equal to `2` then `argv[2]` is equal to `NULL`. That is according to the C Standard `argv[argc]` is equal to `NULL`.

So you need to change this statement

```
h = crypt(h, atoi(argv[2]));
                  ^^^^^^^
```

to

```
h = crypt(h, atoi(argv[1]));
                  ^^^^^^^
```

This is the reason of the segmentation fault.

From the C Standard (5.1.2.2.1 Program startup)

> 2 If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey
> the following constraints:
>
> — The value of argc shall be nonnegative.
>
> — argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.

Also it seems you mean the following condition in the for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
               ^^^^^^^
```

instead of

```
for(int i = 0; i > len; i++)
               ^^^^^^^
```

Also it is better to use the type `size_t` instead of the type `int`. It is the type of the value returned by the function `strlen`.

```
size_t len = strlen(msg);
for( size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
//...
```

Pay attention to that within the function you are not changing the original string. You are just outputting its converted characters.

In this case the function does not make a great sense because it seems it should return the converted string to the caller.

And the returned by the function a pointer to an empty string

```
string c = "";
//...
return c;
```

does not make a sense.

The function should be defined at least the following way.

```
string crypt( string msg, int key )
{
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    
    size_t len = strlen( msg );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < len; i++ )
    {
        msg[i] = (msg[i] + key) % 26;
        printf("%c", msg[i] );
    }

    return msg;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice The for loop mistake and `size_t` is not supported In My ide & I was still working on it My plan is to return the string to the variable h and then print it. But now it is just Printing hello back to me.. At least it is not Showing `Segmentation Fault`

Comment: @ƊααɳιടԋSყҽԃ What compiler and IDE are you using?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I use the [cs50 ide](ide.cs50.io)

Answer (score 0):

`for(int i = 0; i > len; i++)`

This says that the loop starts with `i` at `0`, and will continue *only while `i` is **bigger** than `len`*.

Think about that for a minute.
If `i` starts at `0`, it is never bigger than `len`.

#### The loop will not run.

You intend for the loop to run *while `i` is **less** than `len`*.

Comment: Even if I do it the proper way it shows `Segmentation Fault`

Comment: What input are you providing?   What is `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`? what is variable `h`?